# Translation of a triangle in xy plane by moving its centroid

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

thanks for taking your time to read my question

Consider this problem. Let's say I have three points

A(x1,y1), B(x2,y2) and C(x3,y3).

The centroid of the triangle formed by these three points has the following coordinates:

$ x_c = {x_1 + x_2 + x_3\over 3}, y_c = {y_1 + y_2 + y_3\over 3} $

Now, if I am given a point say with the coordinates 
  $x_{c1}, y_{c1}$

I have to perform the translation of my triangle by moving the centroid of the triangle, so that the centroid of the translated triangle is at the point 
   $ x_c = {x_1 + x_2 + x_3\over 3}, y_c = {y_1 + y_2 + y_3\over 3} $

How can I determine the coordinates of the vertices of the new triangle? I am completely stuck on this.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Add to each of $A,B$, and $C$ the vector $(x_{c1}-x_c,y_{c1}- y_c)$. That gives you the new vertices $A_1,B_1,C_1$.

Comment: @logarithm thank you very much for your help!